# Is there a way to change the byte order of a numpy array without actually changing the values?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array that I created using np.frombuffer() from a file. This file is in big-endian, and I want to create the array reading from the buffer as little-endian values; however, I want to store them in the array as big-endian, so when I pack them again, it automatically packs them as big. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you checked out https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.byteswapping.html#changing-byte-ordering ?

Comment: When I tried this, it changes the data.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work using both .newbyteorder() and .byteswap(), but do I have to use both of these?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but it sounds like you're performing two operations so I'm not surprised you'd need to use two commands.

Comment: I'm just kind of confused on why I would need to perform two operations in the first place. I want to keep the same data and change the byte order. That's what doing the two operations does.